# How to hint types when compiling with llvm-gcc?

Tags: types, llvm, llvm-gcc, type-systems

In some C code, I'm defining a simple static array as a function argument, say:

```
void foo(float color[3]);
```

When I compile it with `llvm-gcc`, it produces the following LLVM assembly language output:

```
define void @foo(float* %n1) nounwind ssp {
```

Is there any way I can hint to the compiler that I'd like it to generate code using an LLVM array `[3 x float]` or vector `<3 x float>` on the stack, instead of a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

`void foo(float color[3]);` is defined by the C standard to be equivalent to `void foo(float *color);`.  Maybe you want `void foo(float (*color)[3])`, or `struct vec { float elems[3]; }; void foo(struct vec color);`?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you cannot. It's C standard / platform ABI which defines the layout of your types, etc.

If you want such fine control over IR emission you'd need to do this by hands (or modify clang, etc.)